# same color pie Chart that difference DataSet in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I make pie chart in SSRS Report

I have 2  Chart and 2 Dataset When I preview My report color not same

[image]

this data are same and Data label are same but difference DataSet I want to show in same color

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps for both pie chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify color scheme by selecting the chart and accessing properties.

[image]

There you can choose a predefined palette or select "Custom" and define your own color scheme by going to clicking CustomPaletteColors. This gives you more flexibility when working with graphs that have more then one section.